# The Entity retrieves the mapped list items in a random sequence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have an entity with a mapped list

```
    public class MovieEntity {
...
          @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
          private Set<MovieOtherTitle> otherTitles;
...
    }
```

The list contains 4 objects (in database)

```
 ID     COUNTRY        TITLE
1952     USA           string2
1953     USA           string1
1954     USA           string3
1955     USA           string4
```

When you view a list, it turns out that the items are in a different order

```
System.out.println("Titles: " + movie.getOtherTitles());

Titles: [MovieOtherTitle(title=string4, country=USA), MovieOtherTitle(title=string2, country=USA), MovieOtherTitle(title=string3, country=USA), MovieOtherTitle(title=string1, country=USA)]
```

The elements in the list are not in the same order as in the database. This situation spoils my application. Can you set these items to be downloaded to the list in the same order?

Comment: I wonder what type you are instantiating that "Set" with? because most of the implementations of Set do NOT preserve any order. You do not have a LIST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a OrderBy annotation to your OneToMany

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("id ASC")
      private Set<MovieOtherTitle> otherTitles;
```

Comment: OK. I have one more question. When saving objects to the database https://pastebin.com/c7U5NGmk.  The elements can also be saved in different order. As in my case, the second element was saved in the database earlier than the first element.